# Cannot disable fragment transaction animation when back button is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I added a pop enter and pop exit animation for fragment transaction. When the back button is clicked,I dont want to play this animation.Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please provide the code snippet where you are setting the custom animation to the fragment transaction?

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out,R.anim_left,R.anim.left);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, use [setCustomAnimations(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int%29) instead of [setCustomAnimations
(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

The animations will not be played while popping the back stack. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I have written the method you need to use. Please check that. Here is an example,

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Use the method with two parameters instead of four. The first two parameters specify the enter animation while the second two specify the exit animation. Hope you understand now.

**UPDATE 2**

I have updated this answer with respect to your scenario. The previous method will only disable the animation before commit and is not useful for you. So, if you want to disable the animations after commit, then you need to perform a few more steps. I will give you a detailed answer on this.

**Step 1**

You need to create a static boolean variable to check when to enable and disable fragment animations,

```
public class FragmentUtils {
    public static boolean mDisableFragmentAnimations = false;
}
```

**Step 2**

You need to override the onCreateAnimation() method of every fragment you want to enable/disable animations,

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (FragmentUtils.mDisableFragmentAnimations) {
        Animation a = new Animation() {};
        a.setDuration(0);
        return a;
    }
    return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
}
```

**Step 3**

And whenever you need to return to your main fragment without animations, just call this method.

```
public void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentUtils.mDisableFragmentAnimations = true;
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    FragmentUtils.mDisableFragmentAnimations = false;
}
```

This will disable the animations first, then pop the fragment from the back stack and turn on the animations again.

I have tried this solution myself and it works perfectly for me keeping in mind your special scenario.

Comment: Aritra Roy,

when fragment created,i want to play animation. Only for the back stack i dont want do this

Comment: I gave you the solution for that. You are using the wrong method.

Comment: What kind of method i should use ?

Comment: I wrote the method in the answer itself. Please check carefully. Have also updated with an example.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment.In my situation,according to a boolean value,I play or dont play animation when back button clicked.So,my custom animation must have 4 parameters.

Comment: So depending on the boolean variable use the methods in your transaction. Simple.

Comment: But i will do this when fragment committed and then back button clicked.

Comment: Is your problem solved or you need more help on this?

Comment: I have updated the answer considering your special scenario. Please check the UPDATE 2 part of the answer.

Comment: Aritra Roy,thank you for update,but i am not using v4 support android that means i don have onCreateAnimation method for fragment.I have onCreateAnimator method istead of onCreateAnimation.

Comment: Then please use the support library. This is the perfect solution for your situation.